# How to explicitly save cobertura-enabled jars in my maven repo?

Tags: deployment, maven, jenkins, maven-assembly-plugin, cobertura

So we have continuous integration in Jenkins of our maven builds.  We have a number of module builds, which are packaged together in an assembly build.  The assembly build is then a dependency of our integration test build, which installs the full package, starts it, runs tests, and shuts it down.  We have nightly cobertura reports running on the module unit tests, but now we want nightly cobertura reports from the integration tests.  I'm comfortable with our ability to setup customized builds for the cobertura reporting using the [cobertura-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/).

The problem is, I don't want to do this all the time, so how do I differentiate this jar in the maven repository?  Is there some way to use a descriptorRef (like jar-with-dependencies) to get it in the same maven repository but with slightly different coordinates?  Then the next question of course is how do I get the assembly build to have different coordinates?  Of course this is likely the same or similar answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really a maven guy, but I think you can deploy this artfifact specially (I use ivy and have a special deploy configuration for the instrumented jars):

Have a look at classifiers:

> **Deploy an artifact with classifier**
>
> Classifiers are the additional text given to describe an artifact.
>
> `artifact-name-1.0-bin.jar   artifact-name-1.0-dev.jar`
>   `artifact-name-1.0-prod.jar`
>
> From the above artifact names, classifiers can be located between the
>   version and extension name of the artifact.
>
> **bin** is used to describe that the artifact is a binary.
>     **dev** is used to describe that the artifact is for development.
>     **prod** is used to describe that the artifact is for production.
>
> To add classifier into your artifact for your deployment, set the text
>   to the classifier parameter.
>
> ```
> mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file:///C:/m2-repo \
>                        -DrepositoryId=some.id \
>                        -Dfile=path-to-your-artifact-jar \
>                        -DpomFile=path-to-your-pom.xml \
>                        -Dclassifier=bin
> ```

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-classifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

I have not understood correctly but If you would like to use over and over again your aggregated jar you can use install plugin?

Let's make clear steps,

- Assemble your file
- Install it to your local repository
- Use this file

In order to make it you should use [install plugin with install-file goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) after the phase you aggregate your file.

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.1</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <phase>anyphase</phase>
         <goals><goal>install-file</goal></goals>
         <configuration>
            <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <packaging>pom</packaging>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then simply reference your jar wherever you want with the necessary coordinates.

Comment: How is saving a dependency transitively even related?  Is my question that confusing that you post a response that is completely unrelated or am I missing something?  FYI, your post is on GETing a transitive dependency, not saving one.

Comment: Sorry Jared :) Really I have misunderstood. If I understood correctly you would like to use again again this aggregate jar? If it is not so, please make it more clear for me to help you.